# Как я могу поместить несколько слов в .split?

Tags: python, split

Мне нужно как-то добавить несколько слов в `.split` \ Как я могу это сделать?

```
user_msg = "{0}".format(message.text)
user_msg.split("/message ")[1]
```

Чтобы оно распозновало `/Message` и `/message`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В сплит никак. Можно взять регулярные выражения:

```
import re
user_msg = re.split('/[mM]essage ', user_msg)
```

Comment: Можно также воспользоваться флагом re.I для регистронезависимого поиска: re.split('/message ', user_msg, flags=re.I)

Comment: Это решение отлично подходит! Однако я получаю вывод примерно таким `['', 'TEXT']` как сделать его таким - `TEXT`?

Comment: @blox интересный вопрос, тут надо поразмыслить.